# Installing Anaconda distribution behind firewall

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am unable to install the Windows Anaconda distribution because of firewall settings that disallows me from downloading `.exe` file types.
Digging a bit further, I found that Anaconda also provides `.zip` files, [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/.winzip/).

Going through that list, I am unable to find the latest version which you can find in their installer archive [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/), which at time of writing is **Anaconda 2018.12 for Windows**.

Is there anywhere that maintains up to date `.zip` archives for the installers?

I am running on a *Windows 10 64 bit machine.*

Comment: Maybe download the latest zip available, install that, then upgrade internally? You can look at this for internal anaconda upgrade: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Comment: Creative. My connection timed out btw, I am thinking that the proxy settings are messing that up too, gotta revisit how to set them again.

Comment: Good luck, let me know if it succeeds!

Answer (score 0):

You can find all installers for anaconda at https://repo.continuum.io/archive/. Windows executables as zip-files are at https://repo.continuum.io/archive/.winzip/

The file you were looking for last year was published three days after your question.